# Rsyslog : Setting a log field using Rainerscript

Tags: rsyslog

There are logs coming from a program (namely supervisord) entering rsyslog. Their message starts with `" real-program-name rest of the message"`, and I'm trying to:

1. Set the programname to `real-program-name` instead of supervisord
2. Remove the programname from the message.

I'm currently doing this:

```
if ($programname == "supervisord") then {
    set $.programname = re_extract($msg, "^ ([^ ]+)", 0, 1, $programname);
    set $.msg = re_extract($msg, "^ [^ ]+ (.+)", 0, 1, $msg);
}
```

(edit : I've tried with `$!` instead of `$.`, same problem)

The following line in my config file/script is

```
if ($programname startswith "real") then {...}
```

So the logs tell me if programname was actually replaced with real-program-name

The logs say :

```
processBATCH: next msg 0: <14>Nov 22 10:51:55 supervisord: real-program-name 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2017:10:51:55 +0000] "GET /blabla
    IF
        var 'programname'
      ==
        string 'supervisord'
eval expr 0x1a4e0b0, type 'CMP_EQ'
eval expr 0x1a4dcd0, type 'V'
rainerscript: (string) var 17: 'supervisord'
eval expr 0x1a4dcd0, return datatype 'S':0
eval expr 0x1a4e0b0, return datatype 'N':1
if condition result is 1
    SET .programname =
      function 're_extract' (id:8, params:5)
        var 'msg'
        string '^ ([^ ]+)'
        0
        1
        var 'programname'
    END SET
eval expr 0x1a4e270, type 'F'
rainerscript: executing function id 8
eval expr 0x1a4dd00, type 'V'
rainerscript: (string) var 1: ' real-program-name 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2017:10:51:55 +0000] "GET /blabla" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"'
eval expr 0x1a4dd00, return datatype 'S':0
eval expr 0x1a4e170, type 'N'
eval expr 0x1a4e170, return datatype 'N':0
eval expr 0x1a4e190, type 'N'
eval expr 0x1a4e190, return datatype 'N':1
re_extract: regexec return is 0
re_extract: regex: end search, found 1
eval expr 0x1a4e270, return datatype 'S':0
    SET .msg =
      function 're_extract' (id:8, params:5)
        var 'msg'
        string '^ [^ ]+ (.+)'
        0
        1
        var 'msg'
    END SET
eval expr 0x1a53290, type 'F'
rainerscript: executing function id 8
eval expr 0x1a534e0, type 'V'
rainerscript: (string) var 1: ' real-program-name 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2017:10:51:55 +0000] "GET /blabla HTTP/1.0" 200 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"'
eval expr 0x1a534e0, return datatype 'S':0
eval expr 0x1a53160, type 'N'
eval expr 0x1a53160, return datatype 'N':0
eval expr 0x1a53180, type 'N'
eval expr 0x1a53180, return datatype 'N':1
re_extract: regexec return is 0
re_extract: regex: end search, found 1
eval expr 0x1a53290, return datatype 'S':0
    IF
        var 'programname'
      STARTSWITH
        string 'real'
eval expr 0x1a545f0, type 'CMP_STARTSWITH'
eval expr 0x1a546b0, type 'V'
rainerscript: (string) var 17: 'supervisord'
eval expr 0x1a546b0, return datatype 'S':0
eval expr 0x1a545f0, return datatype 'N':0
if condition result is 0
```

Which I interpret as : the log comes form supervisor, the regex extraction went well but the `set` had no effect.

What am I doing wrong ?